# Prove that enthalpy is a state function

Tags: thermodynamics

Don't just say that since
$H=U+PV$

Since $U$, $P$ and $V$ are state functions so $H$ is also a state function. What about internal energy, $U$?
$ΔU=q-w$. Even though heat and work are state functions their difference, $ΔU$ is a path function. Please give a rigorous proof.

Comment: The arithmetic combination of other state functions is also a state function. But the combination of path functions *might* or *might not* be a state function. So, $H=U+PV$ is enough to justify that $H$ is a state function since $U$, $P$ and $V$ are state functions.

Comment: I think you have it backwards.  Heat and work are path functions, but their difference, internal energy, is a state function.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed it is possible to say that $H = U + PV$ is a function of state since it is defined in terms of functions of state.

Within thermodynamics, it is not possible to provide a rigorous proof that $\Delta U=q-w$ is a function of state, simply because this is the content of the first principle of thermodynamics. It is a statement summarizing a huge number of direct and indirect experiments. From a statistical mechanics perspective, $U$ is a function of state as a trivial consequence of its definition as equilibrium average of the Hamiltonian. In that case, the first principle reduces to the definition of $q$.

Answer (score 0):

**First Law of Thermodynamics**

> Energy can neither be created nor be destroyed. It can be converted into one form of energy to another.

This suggests that if we transfer energy to the system (either by heat or work) then energy of the system increases, it can't be the case that tranfer of energy to system does not increase the energy of the system as it will violate the first law.
Total energy of the system, $(E)$ = Energy due to the motion of system + Energy due to the particles present in the system (Internal energy $(U)$)
In thermodynamics, we take our sytem to be at rest, so, $E=U$
**Sign convention** Heat added to system and dumped by sytem is +ve and -ve respectively.
Work done on system and by system is +ve and -ve respectively.

**Corollary-1** $dU=$Energy transferred to the system
We can easily prove it by assuming that above statement is not true and then get a contradiction.
As energy is transfered by either heat or work or both
So, $dU=dQ+dW$

**Corollary-2** Assume that internal energy is not a state function. This means that if the system comes back to its original state, then there exists atleast a single process for which $dU\neq 0$
**Proof-** Suppose for that process,
**Case-1** $dU>0$
$\implies dQ+dW>0$
**a) dQ>0 (net heat is taken by the system)**

- $dW>0$ (net work is done on the system)
  This means in the overall process we have to supply heat and do work on the system but nothing happens (as system comes back to its initial state).
  This means we transfer energy to the system but this gets completely destroyed as system remains as it is.
  Contradiction.
- $dW<0$ (net work is done by system)
  As $dQ+dW>0$
  This means net heat supplied to the system is greater than net work done by the system
  Suppose $dQ+dW=\epsilon$ where $\epsilon>0$
  This means we have supplied overall $\epsilon$ amount of heat to the system but nothing happens. This means that this much amount of energy gets destroyed.
  Contradiction

**b)dQ<0**
Same contradiction

**Case 2 $\Delta U<0$**
With similar line of though we get contradiction of energy being created from nothing.

So for all cyclic processes $\Delta U=0$

**Corollary-3** If system goes from state A to B then for all processes there is same change in $U$
**Proof**
Assume for the process-1 and 2 which takes the system from A to B, $\Delta U_1\neq \Delta U_2$
Then there is a process-3 which takes the system from B to A for which $\Delta U_3=-\Delta U_1$ (as for a cyclic process $\Delta U=0$ so $\Delta U_1+(-\Delta  U_1)=0$)
So now if the system is taken from B to A by the reverse of process-3, then
$\Delta U_1+\Delta U_3=0$ but $\Delta U_2+\Delta U_3\neq 0$ as $\Delta U_1\neq\Delta U_2$
So there is a cyclic process which is composed of 2 and 3 for which $\Delta U\neq 0$.
Contradiction of Corollary-2

So, $U$ is a state function.
Basically first law of thermodynamics implies that $U$ is a state function.

As $H(S,P)$ is constructed by Legendre transforming the $U(S,V)$. So, it is the intercept of the $\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}$ for all $U$ and $V$.
If initially the system is in state $U_o,S_o,V_o$ and then comes back to its initial state, then we get the same intercept and thus same $H$. Thus, $\Delta H=0$

So, $H$ is also a state function.

Comment: Your *proof* is assuming the conservation of energy *and* that the only possible change of energy is due to heat transfer and macroscopic work. Therefore you are proving what you have as a hypothesis.

Comment: Yes this is what is called the first law of thermodynamics. We can't prove it theoretically. It is formulated from the observations of several experiments performed by Joule and others. And as a result of which we can say there exist an internal energy function which is a state function.